# Mobile email ignoring max-width CSS

Tags: html, css, email, mobile, responsive-design

I'm trying to build HTML email that works on mobile devices, but when I use the max-width CSS property to define the width of the main table element, iOS and Android both ignore it and stretch the entire email out to fit their default widths.  This breaks my design.  Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML Email</title>
</head>
<body yahoo bgcolor="#ffffff" style="margin: 0; padding: 0; min-width: 100%!important;">
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <table class="content" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width:100%; max-width: 550px;">
                <tr>
                    <td>My Content</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: iOS and Android both support media queries so you can specify the width of your table in a `<style type="text/css">` in the `<head>` of your document.

Comment: My experience to using width:100% instead of max-width: 100% on browsing on mobile device. In desktop version, width is the setting to define the width of element, if the screen size is small then the width, then the element will be resized to the max-width while 100% is the width of the device. But in mobile device, the max-width doesn't work.